# Azure AD and protecting an API

Tags: c#, wpf, api, azure, azure-active-directory

I have been stuck for some days now. 
I have written an API which is hosted on Azure. This takes care of all database calls etc (SQL Azure).
The end user will be using a WPF desktop system.
So I want them to be prompted to log in using their own AD on Azure.
The Rest API in the WPF system is using AutoRest. 
So by calling the below code, this ideally would bring up the Microsoft login, authenticate and I can then pass on the token.

```
var activeDirectoryClientSettings = ActiveDirectoryClientSettings.UsePromptOnly(nativeClientAppCLIENTID, new Uri("https://xxx.azurewebsites.net")); 
return UserTokenProvider.LoginWithPromptAsync(domainName, activeDirectoryClientSettings).Result;
```

This code give me the error : The request body must contain the following parameters: 'client_secret or client_assertion'
I understand this to be a distinction between native and web api calls.

Also the AutoRest is expecting a type of ServiceClientCredentials

```
     public ServiceClientCredentials Credentials
    {
        get { return this._credentials; }
        set { this._credentials = value; }
    }
```

If anyone has had any experience of this scenario it would be helpful.

WPF calls Web APi - Web API is locked down using Azure Ad.
Should be simple to pass the credentials/token via the ServiceClientCredentials and allow viewing of the web API and make calls.
Thanks Scott

Comment: I may have been barking up the wrong tree.
Currently I'm looking at protecting the native app first and allowing that to call the api. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/
Figuring out now.

Comment: I cant get it to work. Using AutoRest, as soon as I bring in the Nuget package Install-Package Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication -Version 2.0.0-preview -Pre
it just breaks with a error. 
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException' from assembly

Comment: I will have to come up with an alternative. A week of figuring has got me nowhere

Comment: For me it was working with ClientRuntime version 0.9.6, but not working with higher versions - this was fine until recently I decided to use Power BI embeded - it has dependency on `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication -Version 2.0.0` and now I'm again having this -> Could not load type 'Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException' from assembly issue... Did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi Prokurors. Sorry, I progressed no further. I am however going to be looking back at this soon. If I get anywhere I will surely let you know. Thanks and good luck. Scott

Comment: A small update - I'm making my own REST service client based on Autorest generated code - found out that `HttpOperationException` can not be generic anymore - removed that and now it works in `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime 2.0.0`. Maybe this post can help you on how to protect your Azure API -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568523/how-to-consume-azure-rest-api-app-with-azure-active-directory-authorization-on

Comment: very much appreciated. Scott