# How to consume Azure REST API App with Azure Active Directory authorization On

Tags: c#, swagger, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps

I have deployed an `API App` to Azure, but I am having problems creating API Client if Authentication (with AAD) is set to ON.

When I try to generate service client (when Authentication is OFF), then client code is generated (it's done with Autorest) and code is working, but when I switch Authentication ON (and Action to take when request is not authenticated is set to `Login with Azure Active Directory`), then

1) service call returned `401 Unauthorized` (without redirecting to AAD login page)

2) Then I tried to generate service client once more (from Project's context menu -> Add -> REST API Client -> then in the dialog box I chose "Select Azure Asset" and pressed OK and got a message `"Failed to download metadata file for Microsoft Azure API App: ...app name..."` (and "no additional information available")

I was implementing AAD according to this Azure manual (using express settings):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/

Was working according to this video, too and everything what is shown in this video was working, except that AAD was not demonstrated... and for me it's not working...

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/connect-2015-what-s-new-in-app-service-api-apps/

**Any suggestions?**

**EDIT**

1) If I enter the request url (that REST API client uses) in web browser - then it returns valid results
2) I found out that I am using REST API without credentials (I thought Azure AD login screen should be presented in this case... but it isn't)

**EDIT 2**

I got some progress - got to the AAD login screen, but after entering credentials I get the `bearer token`, but when I try to query the service, I get an error message:

`AADSTS65005: The client application has requested access to resource 'https....azurewebsites.net'. This request has failed because the client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list.
Trace ID: 4176e...
Correlation ID: 1d612d...
Timestamp: 2016-11-13 18:28:34Z`

These are the steps I've done to get this far:

0) Added Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory nuget pack to client project

1) registered my client app in Azure Active Directory

2) when calling REST API from client application, I am adding `ServiceClientCredentials`

3) when creating ServiceClientCredentials I provide 4 elements
-authority = this is from AAD App registrations -> Endpoints => Federation Metadata Document vērtība (without the starting part `http://login.windows.net/`)

-resource => this is REST API uri (=>Identifier of the target resource that is the recipient of the requested token)

-clientId => this is application id I get after I registered client app in AAD
-redirect Uri => since my client app is a Native application, then this is just any valid url

**How can I specify this resource in my client app?**

`client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution on how to enable AAD authorization to Azure REST API App. Just in case anyone has the same challenge, I hope this will be helpful.

**These are the steps I did:**

1) In App services -> Authentication/authorization

- App Service Authentication => On
- Action to take when request is not authenticated => Login with AAD
- Configured AAD with Express settings (there you have to create Azure
  AD App for you API App - i.e. "App registration" for your service)

2) In Azure Active Directory -> App registrations

- Add registration for your client app
- Edit Manifest of your client app - in the `requiredResourceAccess` section you must add information about REST API App:

  - `resourceAppId` -> insert REST API App id here
  - `resourceAccess {id}` -> OauthPermission id value of REST API (you can get it in REST API's manifest!)

3) In your client application

- generate your REST client using `Autorest` (from solution explorer: `Add\REST API client`) or create it manually
- add `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` nuget pack
- get and use token to access your API with code similar to this:

  ```
      //request
      (..)
      var tokenCreds = getToken();
      ServiceClientCredentials credentials = tokenCreds;

      using (var client = new YourAPI(credentials)) {
      ...
      }
      (..)

      //getting token

  private static TokenCredentials getToken()
  {
      //get this from Federation Metadata Document in 
      //Azure Active Directory App registrations -> Endpoints
      var authority = "f1...";

      //Identifier of the target resource that is the recipient of the requested token
      var resource = "https://yourapi.azurewebsites.net";

      //client application id (see Azure Active Directory App registration
      //for your client app
      var clientId = "a71...";

      //return url - not relevant for Native apps (just has to be valid url)
      var redirectUri = "https://just-some-valid-url.net";

      AuthenticationContext authContext =
      new AuthenticationContext(string.Format
      ("https://login.windows.net/{0}",
  authority));

      AuthenticationResult tokenAuthResult =
      authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,
      clientId,
      new Uri(redirectUri),
      new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;

      return new TokenCredentials(tokenAuthResult.AccessToken);
  }
  ```

Comment: P.S. This resource gave me considerable part of what was necessary to find  the solution http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2016/05/24/aad-authentication-with-rest-api-client.aspx